# my while loop doesn't finish even when the boolean became false how can i fix it?

Tags: java, while-loop

I'm writing code for a game with 2 players take turns, but the while loop keep running in some situation even when the boolean became false.

here is while loop part that has problem

```
while (stone>0)
// this should work only when the num of stones are bigger than 0
{
    if(turn==2*n-1&&stone>0); 
    //if it's odd num turn, it's player1's turn
    {
        System.out.println(p1.getName()+"'s turn - remove how many? : ");
        int remove = keyboard.nextInt();
        s.setStone(remove); 
        stone = stone-s.removeStone();

        System.out.print(stone+"stones left");

        for (i=0;i<stone;i++)
            System.out.print("*");
    }

    //printing asterisk mark to the num of stone left 
    System.out.println(); 

    if(turn==2*n&&stone>0);
    //if it's even num turn, it's player2's turn
    {
        System.out.println(p2.getName()+"'s turn - remove how many? : ");
        int remove = keyboard.nextInt();

        s.setStone(remove);
        stone = stone-s.removeStone();
        System.out.print(stone+"stones left");
        for (i=0;i<stone;i++)
             System.out.print("*");
    } 
    System.out.println();
}
```

so, I intended to finish this loop when the number of stones left becomes 0, it works when player2 removes all stone left(it prints 0 stones left and nothing more), but when it's player 1, who removed all stone left, then there's an error like it prints '0 stones left' and then ' player2's turn - remove how many? '

I wrote while - loop to finish when number of stone become 0, but when player1 make it 0, the loop does not finish and gives player b another turn and make negative amount of stone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that

```
if(turn==2*n-1&&stone>0);
```

and

```
if(turn==2*n&&stone>0);
```

are empty if-statements (meaning: if the condition is true do nothing).

The semicolons at the end of these lines are empty statements - therefore the following blocks (where you ask each player how many stones to remove) are always executed.

Remove those two semicolons and you don't need to change the remainder of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could add:

```
if(!(stone > 0))
        break;
```

on the end of your while-loop.
This way it should stop when you don't have any stones at the end of the loop.